# MDM OS X 10.9 not sending User token in TOKENUPDATE

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, mdm

When enrolling OS X 10.9 with our MDM Server, it is not sending the second token update request with the user token. In the MDM Payload we have added, the server capabilities tag with the value "com.apple.mdm.per-user-connections". For OS X 10.10 and OS X 10.11 this works fine. TokenUpdate is sent twice and the user token is sent.

Is OS X 10.9 compatible with user profiles?

Thanks